# How to get data for childViews from different AJAX Request of a containerView?

Tags: ember.js

I have an application where a ContainerView has more than 6 dynamic childViews. I found out Ember doesn't connect to controllers of respective childViews, my data related to this childViews currently am retreiving in the childViews itself. I have tried even using containerView's controller but childView's data are very independent to each other and needs multiple requests to get the data. Is there a betterway i can do this? Here is sample code am doing rightnow

```
 var App=Ember.Application.create();
App.TestView=Ember.ContainerView.create({

  init: function(){
    var childViews=this.get('childViews');
    childViews.pushObject(Ember.View.create({
      data:this.getData(), 
      getData : function() {
         //Ajax Call

      }

    }));

  }

});

App.TestController=Ember.Controller.create({
  content : []
});
```

Comment: I dont really need `ember-data` as my application mainly analytical kind..

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can fetch the data in the container view's controller, and share them to the child views through computed properties. Something like:

```
App.TestController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  dataForChild1: function () {
    return $.getJSon().data; // make here the ajax call you need
  }.property()

  ...
});

App.TestView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({

  childViews: ['view1', 'view2'],

  view1: Ember.View.extend({
     dataBinding: 'controller.dataForChild1'
  })
});
```

Comment: yea considered this option but problem with this is that `childviews` are dynamic...

Comment: Dynamic in the sense where you don't know their count ?

Comment: would it be possible to post a jsfiddle of your example ? Perhaps the binding stuff could be done during init()

Comment: sry..i tried to add a fiddle..but lot of code needs to be added and made it work in fiddle...

Comment: reg. init() do mean init of controller???..r8 now am adding childViews during init of containerView..

Comment: I think the data should stay in the controller, and the views should be bind to it. Anyway, building childViews during init is fine, so you can probably bind the data at this time